# Change ownership of a file transfered using Samba

Tags: permissions, kubuntu, samba, dolphin, ownership

When I transfer files or folders using Samba from a Windows computer to a Kubuntu computer, the file's owner is set to "Nobody" and I cannot access it.

Is there a way to assign the ownership automatically?

I can change the ownership using the command `sudo chown` and that works fine, except I don't want to type all of that whenever I transfer a file or a folder. I'd like to right click on the folder in Dolphin and select an option and have it done automatically. Is there a way to make that happen? Or, even better, not have it assigned to "Nobody" in the first place...

Comment: Create a folder inside there that has your owenership that nobody owner is normal!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual way you get the saved file with owner = nobody is if you created a guest accessible share on your Linux box. The easiest way to resolve this is to make "nobody" look like you - at least for this share.

You do that by adding an option to /etc/samba/smb.conf:

```
force user = kresimir
```

*Assuming your Kubuntu login user name is kresimir.*

Where you put that line in smb.conf depends on how you created the samba share:

** If the share definition is in smb.conf itself add it to that share definition.

** If you created the share in Dolphin ( Right click > Properties > Share ) add it to the [global] section of smb.conf - right under the `workgroup = WORKGROUP` line is where I would put it.

Either way after editing smb.conf restart smbd:

```
sudo service smbd restart
```

All new files added to the share will have you as owner.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question, but it does solve my problem. :D Thank you! I upvoted it, but I'm not sure whether I should mark it as answered... I guess I'll just edit my question so that this is the answer.